# Angular 2 : Cannot find name 'AmCharts'. while doing aot

Tags: angular, amcharts

While implementing aot in my current project I came across below error, I am using external library AmCharts

Error at path : Cannot find name 'AmCharts'.Cannot find name 'AmCharts'.

Note: every thing is working fine with out aot no compile errors

Answer (score 1):

you need to add syntax

```
define var AmCharts:any;
```

in component as example

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomComponent } from './customCompo';
define var AmCharts:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.html',
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

Comment: Actually it git resolved and the issue is Cannot Find NameSpace Amcharts, and I think its declare and not define